# Having trouble to find the value of the following determinant

Tags: determinant

I came across the following problem from the book Higher Algebra(by barnard and Child) that says:

> Prove that  $\,\,\begin{vmatrix}
> bc &bc'+b'c  &b'c' \\ 
>  ca& ca'+c'a &c'a' \\ 
>  ab&ab'+a'b  &a'b' 
> \end{vmatrix}=(bc')(ca')(ab')$

My Try:  Diving the first row by $b'c'$ ,the second by $c'a'$ ,the third by $a'b'$ and then putting $a/a'=x,b/b'=y,c/c'=z$ we get

$(a'b')(b'c')(c'a')\begin{vmatrix}
yz & y+z  &1 \\ 
 zx& z+x & 1 \\ 
 xy& x+y  & 1 
\end{vmatrix}=.....=(ab'-a'b)(bc'-b'c)(a'c-ac')$

That is the ultimate result I get. Can someone help?

Comment: If that didn't work, just go ahead and compute the determinant manually? It'll take a while but it's infallible.